# VBA условное форматирование

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте! Помогите с решением весьма тривиальной задачи. Сам туп а рекордек катает длиннющие простыни.

Есть Cell(1) и в ней может быть только два значения: "!!!", "ОК". Они переодически меняют в зависимости от других ячеек, но это не важно. Надо чтобы при наличии "!!!" в ячейке Cell(1), ячейка закрашивалась красным. Во втором случае зелёным.

Как используя FormatConditions добиться желаемого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем условное форматирование, если используется VBA? Красить макросом.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        If Target.Value = "!!!" Then
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 77, 52)
        Else
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(90, 184, 130)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*Range("D:D")* - диапазон реагирования макроса.

Код разместить в модуле листа.

```
-------------
```

Если все-таки УФ и в диапазоне может быть только два значения, одно из условий можно исключить

```
Sub SelColor()
    With Selection
        With .FormatConditions
            .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""!!!"""
            .Item(.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 77, 52)
        End With

        .Interior.Color = RGB(90, 184, 130)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Условное форматирование по тому что значения переодически меняются. Я это указал в вопросе, но всё равно спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: Код реагирует на изменение (обрабатывается событие листа). Если нужно заливать при изменении не в родной ячейке, а в диапазоне - дополнить код циклом

Comment: Мой косяк, надо было дописать в вопросе что генерируемый файл хранится в формате excel 2003 без поддержки макросов.

Comment: Понятно. Дополнил сообщение

Comment: А вот это просто отличное решение!

Comment: Нужно красить именно выделенный (*Selection*) диапазон?

Comment: Да, только выделенную ячейку. Ну по сути у меня там целый документ формируется с сотнями строк и столбцов, но это никак не относится к вопросу поэтому я опустил такие детали.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, спасибо, сам решил.

```
Sub Макрос1()
'
' Макрос1 Макрос
'

'
    With Selection.FormatConditions
        .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""!!!"""
        With .Item(.Count).Interior
            .Color = RGB(217, 77, 52)
        End With
        .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="ОК"
        With .Item(.Count).Interior
            .Color = RGB(90, 184, 130)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```